Adjoint in the 2-cat of categories implies adjoint in the 2-cat of triangulated categories
$\def\C{\mathcal{C}}
\def\D{\mathcal{D}}
\def\Triang{\mathsf{Triang}}$I am trying to understand the proof of [M, Proposition 47] (there was another question on this result but their problem is something different). Before stating what it says, I will introduce the necessary definitions (I will use my own notations, not Murfet's). A category with translation is a pair $(\C,T)$ where $\C$ is a category and $T:\C\to\C$ is an auto-equivalence. A morphism of categories with translation $(\C,T)\to(\C',T')$ is a functor $F:\C\to\C'$ along with a natural isomorphism $\xi:FT\cong T'F$. Given morphisms of categories with translation $(F,\xi),(G,\zeta):(\C,T)\to(\C',T')$, a morphism $(F,\xi)\Rightarrow(G,\zeta)$ is a natural transformation $\eta:F\Rightarrow G$ such that
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
FT@>{\eta_T}>>GT\\
@V\xi VV@VV\zeta V\\
T'F@>>T'\eta> T'G
\end{CD}
$$
commutes. Thus, we have a 2-category of categories with translation. The 2-category $\Triang$ of triangulated categories is the subcategory made up of triangulated categories, the triangulated functors as 1-morphisms and all the 2-morphisms between them. For short, we call a 2-morphism in $\Triang$ a trinatural transformation. Given triangulated functors $F:\C\rightleftarrows\D:G$, we say that $F$ is left triadjoint to $G$ if $F\dashv G$ in $\mathsf{Triang}$, i.e., there are trinatural transformations $\eta:1_\C\Rightarrow GF$ and $\varepsilon:FG\Rightarrow 1_\D$ satisfying $1_F=\varepsilon F\circ F\eta$, $1_G=G\varepsilon\circ\eta G$.
The result I am interested in, [M, Proposition 47], says that if $F:(\C,T)\to(\C',T')$ is a triangulated functor between triangulated categories that has a right adjoint $G:\C'\to\C$, then $G$ can be promoted to a triangulated functor in a way that $G$ becomes a right triadjoint to $F$. There's only one claim I don't understand from the proof: Murfet defines the natural transformation $\zeta: GT'\Rightarrow TG$ given by
$$
\tag{1}\label{zeta}
\zeta=\varepsilon_{TG}\circ G\xi_{G}^{-1}\circ GT'\eta
$$
and shows that it is a natural isomorphism. Then he says “observe that $\eta$ is now a trinatural transformation.” My question is: why? Trinaturality of the unit $\eta:1_\C\Rightarrow GF$ amounts to the identity
\begin{align*}
\tag{2}\label{trinat}
\zeta_F\circ G\xi\circ\eta T=T\eta.
\end{align*}
However, I don't see how by plugging \eqref{zeta} into the LHS of \eqref{trinat} I can get the RHS.
In [M, Definition 26], it is said that “if $G$ is right triadjoint to $F$, then $G$ is right adjoint to $F$, but the converse is not true in general,” which is kind of confusing provided that [M, Proposition 47] proves the converse is true.

References
[M] D. Murfet, Triangulated Categories Part I, http://therisingsea.org/notes/TriangulatedCategories.pdf

$\def\C{\mathcal{C}}
\def\E{\mathcal{E}}$I was confusing myself. Murfet is assuming $F\vdash G$ (not $F\dashv G$). Thus the unit and counit are $\eta:1_\E\Rightarrow FG$ and $\varepsilon:GF\Rightarrow 1_\C$, respectively, and the correct trinaturality condition for $\eta$ that we must check is the identity
$$
\label{trinat2}\tag{3}
\xi_G\cdot F\zeta\cdot\eta_{T'}=T'\eta.
$$
Indeed, by plugging \eqref{zeta} into the LHS of \eqref{trinat2} and using naturality of $\eta$ plus the triangle identity $F\varepsilon\cdot\eta_F=1_F$, we get:
\begin{align*}
\xi_G\cdot F(\varepsilon_{TG}\cdot G\xi_{G}^{-1}\cdot GT'\eta)\cdot\eta_{T'}
&=\xi_G\cdot F\varepsilon_{TG}\cdot FG\xi_{G}^{-1}\cdot FGT'\eta\cdot\eta_{T'}\\
&=\xi_G\cdot F\varepsilon_{TG}\cdot FG\xi_{G}^{-1}\cdot \eta_{T'FG}\cdot T'\eta\\
&=\xi_G \cdot \underbrace{F\varepsilon_{TG}\cdot \eta_{FTG}}_{1_{FTG}}\cdot\xi_G^{-1}\cdot T'\eta\\
&=\xi_G\cdot \xi^{-1}_G\cdot T'\eta\\
&=T'\eta,
\end{align*}
which is the RHS of \eqref{trinat2}.
